# Closing all windows and opening another one in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

so I have three windows in my WPF app, a login window, a main window and a confirm log out window.
the confirm log out window has two buttons yes and no, when the user clicks the no button the window gets closed, but when the user clicks the yes button I want the main window and the confirm log out window to get closed and the log in window gets shown.

the problem is that the code works fine but when I close the logout confirmation window the main window is not closed with it

here's my code

```
    private void NoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void YesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        try
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = null;
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserPassword = null;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exp);
        }

        this.Hide();
        Window loginWindow = new Login();
        loginWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I would use the `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` to make the Login/Logout window modal. The flow of your program will be a lot more structured/readable.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I tried that, It didn't work, the problem is that the code works fine but when I close the logout confirmation window the main window is not closed with it

Comment: You could register the `loginWindow.Closed` event to detect when the loginWindow is closed. Same for the logoutWindow.

Comment: okay I'll try that

Comment: note: register the Closed event only ones.

Comment: are you saying that i should check if the logout confirm window is closed, the main window gets closed with it? what if the user pressed the no button? because i tried that and it didn't work the main window is still showing

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen i found the answer, I'll post it in a min, thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this question was that i needed to reach the main window that is calling the log out confirm window to pop up and close it with it, here's the code

```
private void YesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    try
    {
       Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = null;
       Properties.Settings.Default.UserPassword = null;
       Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(exp);
    }

    this.Hide();
    Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    mainWindow.Close();
    Window loginWindow = new Login();
    loginWindow.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

keep in mind that you need to set the Application.Current.MainWindow value in the main window constructor so it doesn't return null sometimes

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the logout from the logout window. Just use the logout window to get a response from the user, then perform the logout (or not) from within the main window.

From the mainwindow:

```
if(logoutWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    try
    {
       Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = null;
       Properties.Settings.Default.UserPassword = null;
       Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(exp);
    }
    ...
    //open login, close this etc.
}
```

In the logout dialog

```
private void YesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    DialogResult = true;
}

private void NoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    DialogResult = false;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, it actually makes a lot of sense.